# What kind of format is this?

Tags: c, syntax, format

When I run the following command in aqbanking

```
aqbanking-cli request -a 0987654321 -c transactions.ctx --transactions --fromdate=20121011
```

a file with the contents as seen below is being created. What kind of format is it, I am trying to find a C library that parses it.

From file **transactions.ctx**:

```
accountInfoList {
  accountInfo {
    char bankCode="1234567890"
    char bankName="Deutsche Bank"
    char accountNumber="0987654321"
    char accountName="Girokonto"
    char owner="MUELLER, MIKE"
    char currency="EUR"
    int  accountType="0"
    int  accountId="42"

    statusList {
      status {
        int  time="1349956800"

        notedBalance {
          value {
            char value="8799384%2F100"
            char currency="EUR"
          } #value

          int  time="1349956800"
        } #notedBalance
      } #status
    } #statusList
  } #accountInfo
} #accountInfoList
```

Comment: When you say "In a created file from my banking app" it is somewhat unclear. Is this a file that the app you created has produced, or is this a data file from a third party? If from 3rd party, ask them. If from yourself, it may(almost certainly will) be worth reconsidering the serialization format used.

Comment: Ahhh. Well in that case, I'd be inclined to download the aqBanking source-code and fire-up a text editor and start searching for some of the keywords in the output file. That should tell you in under an hour or so where the code to output it resides in the source. This would quite likely reside in a function whose name would give away the name of the function to import the same data. I note that aqBanking appears to support both import and export (see here: http://freecode.com/projects/aqbanking) so with that in mind, I'd just use their code if I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a standard file format. It's a file format from the Gwenhywfar library. http://freecode.com/projects/gwenhywfar

From their feature list in the README,

```
High-level functions for parsing files with a simplified "XML-like"
format and accessing them like a hierarchical database (src/parser/)
It is able to process valid XML files, too.
```

There are C++ function in the src/parser folder you could probably use, but the documentation looks a bit lacking.

Comment: Thanks, I've found a way to internally convert the file to csv. The command is: aqbanking-cli listtrans --exporter=csv --ctxfile=transactions.ctx -o transactions.csv